# How can I have a user control button behave differently on different aspx pages?

Tags: asp.net

We have a user control that has a button. We use this user control on different aspx pages. We want the button to behave differently on different pages (dynamically). How might I achieve this goal?

Comment: Please support your question with more information using your code.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using `event` in aspx.cs.

Suppose I have a button on user control

```
<asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" Text="Click Me" onclick="btnClick_Click" />
```

on the user control code behind you can write as follows

```
public event EventHandler ButtonClickDemo;
protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ButtonClickDemo(sender, e);
}
```

No on your `aspx.cs` content page you can use it as follows

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Demo1.ButtonClickDemo += new EventHandler(Demo1_ButtonClickDemo);
}

protected void Demo1_ButtonClickDemo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Response.Write("It's working");
}
```

Where `Demo.ascx` is the user control, so you can write `Demo1.ButtonClickDemo`

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon how dynamic you want this functionality to be, it may be easier to simply create a property on your user control that would be set by your ASPx (if you can pass the information declaratively) or your codebehind (if you need to pass it programmatically). c.f. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26db8ysc.aspx for more information on creating user control properties.